# Zend Sessions not stored for step3

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session-namespace

I have used zend session as bellow..

```
$test = new Zend_Session_Namespace('test');

$test->test = "test text";
```

But when i move from one step to another step its working fine and echoes value Not on step3. even i tried using $_SESSION direct (because am desperate this to work ). But i have same problem that session not stored. Site seems almost broken when i use mozilla and IE. Not only in my PC But i have tested in multiple systems.
Tried clearing cookies, used cookie enabled browser only.

SO please suggest me what could be the posible problem in doing above. even i have inserted `zend_session::start();`

Thanks in advance,
Sanjeevk,

Comment: Are you moving (in step 3, whatever it is) to a different domain or protocol?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't left any `session_start()` hanging out there somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't provided any useful code for what you are trying to accomplish, so I'm going to guess.
I have encountered a problem similar to this as well.
 My issue was simply trying to persist a page number from the paginator so I could perform an operation on a record and then return to the same page in the previous action.

The problem I was having was that the controller would overwrite the session data every time I called the action (page refresh), so while the page number would persist to other actions as soon as I called the original action the session would be over written and the page would reset to 1.

My solution was to get the page number from the view script and then feed it back to the controller later.

```
//the view script
<?php $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('page'); $page = $this->paginator->getCurrentPageNumber(); ?>
```

so now when call `$session->page` anywhere in my controller/actions the data is still there and doesn't overwrite until the view is actually rendered, which is exactly what I needed.

You may be encountering something similar. Because of the way PHP and Zend Framework operate you may be inadvertently over writing your session data.

If this doesn't help, please provide more information and maybe an answer can be found.

Hope this provides some help or at least hints.